# AutocompleteTextView not properly working listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, autocompletetextview, custom-adapter

I am developing one application in which I am having one listview .In that each row is having one textview and one AutoCompleteTextview. now what I want is to make that autocompletetextview editable i.e once when my list is populated with some data in it I want to edit some of the autocompletetexviews and then send updated data to the server.Is there any solution for that? I wasted my 2 days on that and I need this very urgently.

Here is my `customAdapter's getview()` method. I can successfully populate data within listview and I have added "`addOnTextChangedListener`" to the autocomletetextview. But when I filtered data it cannot set to the auotocompletetext i.e `autocomtextview.settext(filtereddata)` is not performing.I am getting filtered text in `onTextChanged()` In my code I wrote this but I dont know actually where to put this.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
   LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

if(convertView==null)
{
    convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_applwizard_extuser_listrow,null);


TextView appl_Name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ext_app_name);

auto_brand_Name=(AutoCompleteTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ext_auto_brand_txt);
auto_brand_Name.setFocusable(true);
auto_brand_Name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

ToggleButton toggle_status=(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ext_toggle_cover);
LinearLayout ll_save_btn=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_ext_btn_appsubmit);

try
{

    appl_Name.setText(alApplianceDetails.get(position).getAppliance_Name().toString());

    if(alApplianceDetails.get(position).getStatus()==true)
    {
        toggle_status.setChecked(true);
    }
    else
    {
        toggle_status.setChecked(false);
    }


    if(alApplianceDetails.get(position).getBrand_Id()!=0)
    {
        String brand_name=null;
        brand_name=dbHandler.getBrand_id(String.valueOf(alApplianceDetails.get(position).getBrand_Id()));
        Log.d("brand name", brand_name);

        auto_brand_Name.setText(brand_name);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("brand name", "no brand");

    }


    try
    {
    auto_brand_Name.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int position, long id) 
        {
             String selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
             //auto_brand_Name.setText(selection);

             Log.d("adpter value..",""+parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString());

             try
             {
                AutoCompleteTextView brnd=(AutoCompleteTextView)view;
                //Log.d( "text value.....",brnd.getText().toString());
                brnd.setText(filteredVal);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    auto_brand_Name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) 
        {
            if(alApplianceDetails.get(position).getAppliance_TypeId()!=0)
            {
                String app_name=null;
                app_name=dbHandler.getApp_id(String.valueOf(alApplianceDetails.get(position).getAppliance_TypeId()));

                appliance=app_name;
                Log.d("app_name",app_name);

            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("app_name", "No App");
            }

            alBrands.clear();

            getBrand();                 
            for(int i=0;i<alBrand_Common_Objects.size();i++)
            {                   
                alBrands.add(alBrand_Common_Objects.get(i).getcommon_name());

            }

            Log.d("brands_list", alBrands.toString());
            aaBrand =new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, alBrands);

            auto_brand_Name.setThreshold(1);
            auto_brand_Name.setAdapter(aaBrand);
            auto_brand_Name.postInvalidate();
            auto_brand_Name.invalidate();
            auto_brand_Name.showDropDown();

            aaBrand.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            //aaBrand.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
        {
            Log.d("filtered value...", s.toString());
            filteredVal=s.toString();

            //auto_brand_Name.setText(s.toString());

        }



        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
        {
            try
            {
            //auto_brand_Name.setText(filteredVal);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Never put `EditText` in `Listview`, `EditText` will loose focus any time when there is any change in list (scrolling,refresh).

Comment: I am using AutoCmpleteTextView within listview because I want this functionality for multiple autocomTextviews so that i can update existing record at run time and send to the server. instead of listview any other way is there to achive this in my application?

Comment: You can keep `listview`, but instead of putting `editext` put `textView`, and when user clicks on `textView`, show a `popup/dialog` with `editext/AutocompleteTextView`.

Or you have to use `ScrollView`.